# bootstrap 4 css nav-item is not working properly in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

left nav panel is working fine in desktop view but when i toggle it to mobile view nav-item shows only last item rather than 3 of them.in mobile view it shows only last link which is Equip 3 it suppose to show all navigation links when click on EquipS which are Equip 1,Equip 2,Equip 3.they are level 1 nav links
it work fine in normal view.
here is the code:

```
        <li class="nav-item" id="#ListMenu">

            

            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Equipcollapse"
                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseEquips">
                <i class="fas fa-wave-square"></i>
                <span>EquipS</span>
            </a>

             <!-- Start Equip-ID-1 -->
             <div id="Equipcollapse" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingEquip-1" data-parent="#ListMenu">
                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#Equipscollapselevel1-ID-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsetest"
                        style="color:black;">
                        <span> Equip 1</span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="Equipscollapselevel1-ID-1" class="collapse"
                        aria-labelledby="Equipscollapselevel1-ID-1" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                        <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                            <!-- Start Materials-ID 1-1 -->
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#Materialscollapselevel2-ID-1-1" aria-expanded="true"
                                aria-controls="collapsetest" style="color:black;">
                                <span> Material-ID 1</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="Materialscollapselevel2-ID-1-1" class="collapse"
                                aria-labelledby="Materialscollapselevel2-ID-1-1" data-parent="#Equipscollapselevel1-ID-1">
                                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">

                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Standards process</a>
                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Customs process</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Materials-ID 1-1 -->
                            <!-- Start Materials-ID 1-2 -->
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Materialscollapselevel2-ID-1-2"
                                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsetest" style="color:black;">
                                <span> Material-ID 2</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="Materialscollapselevel2-ID-1-2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="Materialscollapselevel2-ID-1-2"
                                data-parent="#Equipscollapselevel1-ID-1">
                                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">

                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Standards process</a>
                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Customs process</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--End Materials-ID 1-2-->
                            <!-- Start Materials-ID 1-3 -->
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Materialscollapselevel2-ID-1-3"
                                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsetest" style="color:black;">
                                <span> Material-ID 3</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="Materialscollapselevel2-ID-1-3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="Materialscollapselevel2-ID-1-3"
                                data-parent="#Equipscollapselevel1-ID-1">
                                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">

                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Standards process</a>
                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Customs process</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--End Materials-ID 1-3-->

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Equip-ID-1 -->

            <!--*********************************************-->

             <!-- Start Equip-ID-2 -->
             <div id="Equipmentcollapse" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingEquip-2" data-parent="#ListMenu">
                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#collapse-Equips2-ID-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseEquip-2"
                        style="color:black;">
                        <span> Equip 2</span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="collapse-Equips2-ID-2" class="collapse"
                        aria-labelledby="collapse-Equips2-ID-2" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                        <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                            <!-- Start Materials-ID 1-1 -->
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapse-Equips2-Materials-ID-2-1" aria-expanded="true"
                                aria-controls="Collapse" style="color:black;">
                                <span> Material-ID 1</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="collapse-Equips2-Materials-ID-2-1" class="collapse"
                                aria-labelledby="collapse-Equips2-Materials-ID-2-1" data-parent="#collapse-Equips2-ID-2">
                                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">

                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Standards process</a>
                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Customs process</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Materials-ID 1-1 -->
                            <!-- Start Materials-ID 1-2 -->
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" 
                            data-target="#collapse-Equipments2-Materials-ID-2-2"
                                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse" style="color:black;">
                                <span> Material-ID 2</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="collapse-Equipments2-Materials-ID-2-2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="collapse-Equips2-Materials-ID-2-2"
                                data-parent="#collapse-Equips2-ID-2">
                                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">

                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Standards process</a>
                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Customs process</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--End Materials-ID 2-2-->
                            <!-- Start Materials-ID 2-3 -->
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" 
                            data-target="#collapse-Equips2-Materials-ID-2-3"
                                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse" style="color:black;">
                                <span> Material-ID 3</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="collapse-Equips2-Materials-ID-2-3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="collapse-Equips2-Materials-ID-2-3"
                                data-parent="#collapse-Equips2-ID-2">
                                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">

                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Standards process</a>
                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Customs process</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--End Materials-ID 1-3-->

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Equip-ID-2 -->

            <!--*********************************************-->   

              <!-- Start Equip-ID-3 -->
              <div id="Equipcollapse" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingEquip-3" data-parent="#ListMenu">
                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#collapse-Equips3-ID-3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseEquip-3"
                        style="color:black;">
                        <span> Equip 3</span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="collapse-Equips3-ID-3" class="collapse"
                        aria-labelledby="collapse-Equips3-ID-3" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                        <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                            <!-- Start Materials-ID 3-1 -->
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapse-Equips3-Materials-ID-3-1" aria-expanded="true"
                                aria-controls="Collapse" style="color:black;">
                                <span> Material-ID 1</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="collapse-Equips3-Materials-ID-3-1" class="collapse"
                                aria-labelledby="collapse-Equips3-Materials-ID-3-1" data-parent="#collapse-Equips3-ID-3">
                                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">

                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Standards process</a>
                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Customs process</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Materials-ID 3-1 -->
                            <!-- Start Materials-ID 3-2 -->
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" 
                            data-target="#collapse-Equips3-Materials-ID-3-2"
                                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse" style="color:black;">
                                <span> Material-ID 2</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="collapse-Equips3-Materials-ID-3-2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="collapse-Equips3-Materials-ID-3-2"
                                data-parent="#collapse-Equips3-ID-3">
                                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">

                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Standards process</a>
                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Customs process</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--End Materials-ID 3-2-->
                            <!-- Start Materials-ID 3-3 -->
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" 
                            data-target="#collapse-Equips3-Materials-ID-3-3"
                                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse" style="color:black;">
                                <span> Material-ID 3</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="collapse-Equips3-Materials-ID-3-3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="collapse-Equips3-Materials-ID-3-3"
                                data-parent="#collapse-Equips3-ID-3">
                                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">

                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Standards process</a>
                                    <a class="collapse-item" href="process_tables.html" style="color: black;">
                                        Customs process</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--End Materials-ID 3-3-->

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Equip-ID-3 -->   

        </li>
```